# How to display line over line chart for requests in Azure Monitor workbook?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am trying to create a requests per minute time (RPM) chart in Azure Monitor workbook for requests which are throttled and non-throttle in the form of two lines (overlayed). I manage to create a time chart for RPM with one line but what is the best way to show two distinct lines for each type of request.

[image]

Here is the KQL for the chart. Thinking to perform self-join on the table (T) based on ResultType (Throttled and Non-Throttled) but not sure about it. Maybe a better solution out there.

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, ResultType:string, ResultSignature:string, CorrelationId:string) [
"2022-03-02T14:25:21.8262878Z", "Throttled", "200", "be8bd024-8f5c-4a01-9703-2945ef3bc8ba",
"2022-03-02T14:25:35.3729584Z", "Throttled", "200", "66ed2194-ffa2-43ae-96f4-d3d8d1fb4c4d",
"2022-03-02T14:25:35.5681385Z", "Throttled", "200", "37b33938-0498-4e66-b16e-8c77ac9cf6b9",
"2022-03-02T14:25:35.9571988Z", "Throttled", "200", "cc9a0638-37b2-4c25-8578-8df206896de0",
"2022-03-02T14:25:38.1975426Z", "Throttled", "200", "2b70359d-1732-4cfe-8eda-ef993bbd638a",
"2022-03-02T14:25:38.3044257Z", "Throttled", "200", "9143b5fc-c074-467a-bb97-9765e698e3ff",
"2022-03-02T14:25:40.0240219Z", "Throttled", "200", "8cd18445-556e-44fe-81d8-38e261fddb02",
"2022-03-02T14:25:48.3866310Z", "Throttled", "200", "c5d21533-e1cd-484a-aee2-d05b804eecf0",
"2022-03-02T14:26:03.2572998Z", "Throttled", "200", "46c47f34-2402-45e1-ba8b-fea4d2e59640",
"2022-03-02T14:28:23.1553098Z", "Non-Throttled", "302", "fa309b65-b0b7-43d3-b3aa-9b6de6ce17cb",
"2022-03-02T14:28:23.9385460Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "daedb13f-8b3e-4268-9803-b3bf8039d776",
    ];
T 
    | project Timestamp, ResultType, ResultSignature , CorrelationId
    | summarize TotalRequests = count() by bin(Timestamp,1m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `ResultType` as an aggregation key.

i.e. you can replace this:

`| summarize TotalRequests = count() by bin(Timestamp,1m)`

with this:

`| summarize TotalRequests = count() by ResultType, bin(Timestamp,1m)`